# Enabling rule chain alarms with MQTT doesn't work in thingsboard

Tags: mqtt, alarm, thingsboard

When I am sending telemetry to devices in thingsboard using MQTT the alarms I have set up (using this guide https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/) doesn't work. It does work to begin with when using POST requests, but it stops working as soon as I use MQTT for a device. The device seems to always be active as indicated by the server attribute "active".

### The setup

- send inactivity to alarm trigger (rule chain)
- send activity to alarm clear (rule chain)
- save server attributes (rule chain)
- set inactivityTimeout server attribute to a value (60000ms in my case) for a device

[image]

[image]

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

### Other sources I have checked:

Same problem, but he fixed it by changing the DEFAULT_STATE_CHECK_INTERVAL in the configuration yml file. My file seems to have reasonable values for this - https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/1334
    
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mqtt is keeping the heartbeat alive and keeping the device always active.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).